How to create multiple independent spaces and run them simultaneously in Unity
I created a project using unity mirror assets.
I separated the server Unity project and the client Unity project.
Using the central processing server method, everything has to be processed on the server for all games. So, I have to manage all games in one project (server unity project).
I want to dynamically create and manage an independent world space for each of these games.
What should I do?
It’s like running multiple scenes simultaneously
1.
SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
I tried this, but it only created in one space.
If that happens, the game will have to be distinguished by coordinates and there will be many objects with Rigidbody, which will likely consume a lot of computer resources.
2.
I also thought about distinguishing different games into different layers, but the number of layers is limited to 32.

If I understand what you are trying to do, then you may have misunderstood this "central processing server method". There is no reason to have all your games running in one Unity project: it will be terribly laggy and just complicate things in development.
Instead, you should make a game server project per game and then on your server, run the different builds for the different games you would like to have running.
If you insist on having a "one project fits all" approach, then you could potentially make a server project that utilizes some sort of shared API that all your game clients can communicate with, and run multiple instances of this build on your server.
What I'm trying to say is, your server can run multiple instances of software at the same time. You don't need to implement this in Unity.

Sorry for the delay in receiving your message.
The game I'm talking about is multiple matching in one game.
For example, Players A, B, C, and D are connected to GameA, A is playing with B, and C is playing with D.
In this case, you need to simulate two matches at once.
If this game requires physics calculations, it would be efficient for each game to have its own independent world space.
